# Undefined method for quiz model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A survey has many questions which has many answers:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :reject_if => -> (a) {a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :survey
    has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => -> (a) {a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
end
```

in SurveysController, I do this:

```
def show
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    @questions = @survey.questions
    @answers = @questions.answers
  end
```

and I get an error:

```
undefined method `answers' for #<Question::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f7f68af6948>
```

and rails points to this line as the problem:  `@answers = @questions.answers`

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're trying to load ALL answers from ALL questions, but you're using a syntax that is designed to load ALL answers from a SINGLE question.

For example, this would be correct:

```
@question_1 = @survey.questions.first    # Notice the `first`
@answers = @question_1.answers           # Gets all answers for the `first` question
```

See how I'm getting a single `question` and then getting its answers? That is correct.

Now, if you DO want to get ALL answers for ALL questions, you would benefit from using the `collect` method:

```
@questions = @survey.questions
@answers = @questions.collect(&:answers)
```

What this `collect` method essentially does is run an `each` loop through each question and "collects" its children (the `answers`) into an array.

--

A less-concise, albeit more efficient approach would be to avoid N+1 queries and use `includes` instead of `collect`

```
@answers = []
@questions.includes(:answers).each do |q| 
    @answers << q.answers
end
```

Comment: I get it now.  Thank you!